# What approach should I take to install Bash on a Synology NAS (RS815RP+) inside a corporate network?

Tags: linux, bash, synology

I am attempting to install an application on my Synology NAS (RS815RP+ running DSM 5.1-5022). The installation appears to have failed due to the Bash shell not being available. Ash is the default shell in Synology’s DSM.

To install Bash, it’s recommended that I utilize `ipkg`, which appears to require being online to access package repositories. It appears I will need to install Bash manually, which [appears to be built from source](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Basic-Installation.html#Basic-Installation) when done manually. Is there an alternative route that I have not come across? It appears that I will first need to install `make`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: are you sure there is room enough to install `Bash`? The reason why you have an Almquist shell (ash) is that it is embedded into BusyBox, which is of course very light weight ompared with Linux, and thus suitable for embedded systems.

Comment: I've got 1.2 Gb  available on the system drive.  I don't know how much bash needs.  I hope it is less than that.

Comment: 1.2Gb or 1.2GB? But in any case, you are certainly good to go, no problem.

Comment: GB.  Oops.  I've always resolve bits and bytes by context.  Clever.